# How to use recursion to check if a string is composed of a pattern?

Tags: java, string, recursion, pattern-matching

How can I create a recursive method that takes two parameters, a string and the length of a pattern, and check if the string is composed of repeated occurrences of the given length?

This is what I came up with so far, the code is still incomplete but I don't know what to do next.

```
    public static boolean checkPattern(String str, int pattern) {
        if(str.length() % pattern != 0)
            return false;
        String sub = str.substring(0, pattern);
//        if(str.matches(sub)) {
//            return checkPattern(str, pattern); 
//        }
        return false;
    }
```

The outpot should be like this:

```
Enter pattern: abcdabcd 4
abcdabcd is composed of a pattern of length 4.

Enter pattern: abcdabcd 3
abcdabcd is not composed of a pattern of length 3.
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Currently not able to test this but it should be in the Ballpark of what you are trying to archive

```
public static boolean checkPattern(String str, int patternLength) {
    if(str.length() % patternLength != 0)
        return false;
    if (str.length() == patternLength) {
        return true;
    }
    String sub1 = str.substring(0, patternLength);
    String sub2 = str.substring(patternLength, patternLenght * 2);
    if(sub1.equals(sub2)) {
        return checkPattern(str.substring(patternLength), patternLength); 
    }
    return false;
}
```